# Контейнерный дизайн

Tags: html, css

Как разделить страницу на блоки (css) и задать фон каждого из блоков?

Comment: Это тема для изучения, а не для вороса

Answer (score 1):

Зачем задавать такой же вопрос? Вам же уже ответили в предыдущем вопросе

Вообще, как создавать и работать с "блоками" (чаще это называют слои, если я правильно понял, о чём вы) - это целая отдельная тема. Если вкратце - чтобы сделать слой, создайте блочный элемент -

```
<div></div>
```

У него вы можете задать любые свойства, необходимые вам (ширину/высоту, цвет, положение на экране и т.п.). Делается это через свойства CSS Например

```
<div style="backgroung-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; >top: 50px; left: 20px;">Содержимое слоя</div>
```

А задать фон можно, как уже написали выше, одним из свойтв:

```
background-color: yellow;
background-image: url(ссылка на изображение)
```

ещё можно на всякий случай написать свойство `background: no-repeat;` чтобы фон не повторялся

Более подробно о любых свойствах CSS и HTML можно узнать тут.

Answer (score 1):

Я уже отвечал на данный вопрос, но не могу найти топик. Но как и ожидал вопрос может возникнуть повторно! По этой причине я написал две статьи на блоге своем 
[Построение и виды сайтов(html+css)](http://nosensus.com/types-of-sites-html-css-part1/) html построение.
И вторая часть [CSS верстка](http://nosensus.com/types-of-sites-html-css-part2/) 
Если возникнут вопросы я буду рад ответить.

> А задать фон блокам можно через 
> background: #000;  либо поставить
>
> картинку background: url(../i/img.png)
>
> no-repeat 0 0;  где
> url(../i/img.png)-путь до картинки и
> сама картинка не забываем формат
> картинки. 
> no-repeat - не повторять
>
> или repeat-x repeat-y повторение
> картинки по оси ординат.
>
> repeat - повторение по всем направлениям.